# appending function attributes to a Python class at runtime

Tags: python, class, attributes, decorator

I am appending methods to a class using a decorator

```
def add_functions_as_methods(functions):
    def decorator(Class):
        for function in functions:
            setattr(Class, function.__name__, function)
        return Class
    return decorator
```

and I use it at class declaration

```
mylist_functions=[a,b,c]
@add_functions_as_methods(mylist_functions)
class myclass(abstract_base):
        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            pass
```

Now I would like to read `mylist_functions` from a json file.
How do I do that without using `eval`?

I would create instances using

```
myinstance=myclass('myconf.txt')
```

and ideally `myconf.txt` should be

```
{'a':a}
```

However, if I run the simple

```
json.loads('{"a":a}')
```

it does not work

Comment: can you show us a sample input json file ?